# insert blob not working (mysql_real_escape_string)

Tags: mysql-real-escape-string

I am trying to copy image blobs from one table to another, and it is not working, since the mysql_real_escape_string () is no longer available. The special characters in the blob are blocking the insert and I can't figure out how to correct this. Your help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
foreach ($dbh->query($query_images) as $images-1) {
  $ins = "INSERT INTO images-2 SET image_blob='".images-1['image_blob']."'";
  $dbh->exec($ins);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have:

```
 $ins = "INSERT INTO images-2 SET image_blob='".images-1['image_blob']."'";
```

when you likely want:

```
 $ins = "INSERT INTO images-2 SET image_blob='".$images-1['image_blob']."'";
```

but that could just be a typo in your post.

You can do this in pure MySQL and not have to iterate through each row in the images-1 table:

```
INSERT INTO images-2 (image_blob) VALUES (SELECT image_blob FROM images-1)
```

If it is some kinda of escaping problem I would suggest going with the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) stuff in PHP:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=db', $user, $pass);
foreach($dbh->query($query_images) as $images-1) {
    $sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO images-2 SET image_blob=?")
    $sth->execute([$images-1['image_blob']]);
}
```

I did not test any of this code but just put it together based on documentation and experience.

Comment: I tried this using the PDO method and got an error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null. But I am unable to see where there error could be. Maybe because I have been looking at it too long. Can anyone spot the error?
    $ii = "INSERT INTO images SET image_id=0,image_blob=?,image_size=?,image_width=?,image_height=?,image_type=?,image_attr=?";
    $sth = $pdo->prepare($ii);
    $sth->execute([$ri['image_blob'],$ri['image_size'],$ri['image_width'],$ri['image_height'],$ri['image_type'],$ri['image_attr']]);

Comment: Doesn't look like you have created the PDO object. I have revised my example to include a sample of how to do that.